# change partition label keeping filesystem

Tags: partition

doing `lsblk -o type,name,label,partlabel`

- LABEL is at the partition level, and is set via `mkfs -L <label>` when creating the file system, it is this one used in fstab for mounting
- PARTLABEL can be set via `parted <block device>  -name <partlabel>`

Is there a way to change the partition label used for mounting without blowing away the existing file system?  I want to modify just *LABEL* for existing partitions that would be either ext4, xfs, or ntfs.

Comment: I don't really get your question as the last two sentences contradict each other. First you ask how to change "partition label", so `partlabel`. But then you say you want to modify LABEL, which is the `label`. So which one it is?

Answer (score 5):

`e2label` for ext2/ext3/ext4 and `ntfslabel` for ntfs file system.

`man ntfslabel`:

> ```
>   ntfslabel - display/change the label on an ntfs file system
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
>   ntfslabel [options] device [new-label]
> ```

`man e2label`:

> ```
>   e2label - Change the label on an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
>   e2label device [ volume-label ]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The LABEL is a property of the file-system. You change it with the tool appropriate to the file-system:

```
tune2fs -L volume-label device
ntfslabel  device new-label
xfs_admin -L label device
```

The file-system needs to be unmounted.

Comment: for `f2fs`, any clues? tx

Comment: GPT supports labels on partitions, offset 0x38 in [Partition Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries_(LBA_2%E2%80%9333)).

Answer (score -1):

There is also `fatlabel` for Fat filesystems. It can be used like

```
fatlabel /dev/sda1 'NewLabel'
```

and changes the label for an existing FAT partition.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/455324)

Comment: Does it not answer the question of how one changes the /label/ for a filesystem of the type fat?

Comment: True, but the question explicitly stated _I want to modify just LABEL for existing partitions that would be either ext4, xfs, or ntfs._ If you highlight the difference more prominently and add a usage example on how to apply the tool, your answer may still be useful, though.